# How can i set up CloudFlare Tunnels with my specific existing setup?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, cloudflare-argo

I current have got a Nginx webserver with basic CloudFlare DNS proxy. I would like to tunnel all my traffic from all subdomains and domanis to my server and then use nginx server_name to set where the domains go to. I use nginx as reverse proxy and for serving static content. Because of the static content, I don't think I can use the default setup for tunnels because, from what I've seen, every tunnel wants its own port.

I already have watched multiple videos and read many articles about CloudFlare tunnels but it seems that no article covers my specific setup.